# Ordering Parent / Child -- Hierarchical data in SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this.
parent_tree column contains colon separated parent tree i.e. 
Grand Grand Parent **:** Grand Parent **:** Parent

```
parent_tree                             | name                | Type

All Liabilities:Current Liabilities     | Salaries Payable    | Liabilities
Assets                                  | Current Assets      | Assets
null                                    | All Liabilities     | Parent
All Liabilities                         | Current Liabilities | Parent
null                                    | Assets              | Parent
.
.
```

**Question**
Now I want to run a select query (select --- from table order by ----) to get result in the following order i.e. parent first and then its children:

```
parent_tree                             | name                | Type

null                                    | All Liabilities     | Parent
All Liabilities                         | Current Liabilities | Parent
All Liabilities:Current Liabilities     | Salaries Payable    | Liabilities
null                                    | Assets              | Parent
Assets                                  | Current Assets      | Assets
```

So the main question is what should I write in **order by**

I tried following but result is not in correct order:

```
select * from table order by if( type = 'Parent', concat(coalesce(parent_tree,name), ':' ,name), parent_tree ), length(parent_tree), if(type = 'Parent', 0, 1), type";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with following query

```
select * from table order by 
 order by concat(  if(parent_tree is null, name, concat(parent_tree, ':', name) ), ':');
```